# Calculating the average of numbers in a single textbox vb

Tags: vb.net, textbox, average

I need to take all the numbers in a textbox, and turn that into an average number.

My code:

```
Dim dMods1 = "\\DirectPathToSpecificFolder"
Dim dMods2 = "\\DirectPathToSpecificFolder"
Dim dMods3 = "\\DirectPathToSpecificFolder"
Dim dMods4 = "\\DirectPathToSpecificFolder"

Dim fileCount1 As Integer = Directory.GetFiles(dMods1).Length
Dim fileCount2 As Integer = Directory.GetFiles(dMods2).Length
Dim fileCount3 As Integer = Directory.GetFiles(dMods3).Length
Dim fileCount4 As Integer = Directory.GetFiles(dMods4).Length

        Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim array = TextBox2.Lines
    TextBox2.Clear()
    If Not dMods1 Is Nothing Then

        For Each FilePath As String In Directory.GetFiles(dMods1, "*.txt")
            TextBox2.Text &= System.IO.File.ReadAllText(FilePath) & vbNewLine
        Next
        For index = 0 To array.GetUpperBound(0)
            Debug.WriteLine(array)
        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

Right now it will come with the contents of .txt files in the specific folder, and put it in textbox2. But it will come with this `vbNewLine`, so creating space between the numbers.

How can I calculate the average of these numbers and put that into a `label1`?

Comment: `textBox.Lines` will give you an array of the data and `textBox.Lines.Count-1)` will tell you how many.there are

Comment: @Plutonix If i try and say `Label1.Text = TextBox2.Lines` i get "Value of type '1-dimensional array of String' cannot be converted to 'string'". But the `Count-1` works great

Comment: ...and the error msg is correct.  As I said, *textBox.Lines will give you an **array** of the data*  Iterate (walk thru) the array to get the values in the array

Comment: Ahh okay, still working through all of the terms (eg. arrays). Ill search a bit for my self before looking here again, but how would i go about "Iterating" an array?

Comment: [Arrays in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx) ... there is a while subsection on how to iterate

Comment: @Plutonix Thank you for that. But, i cant figure it out. Could you give an example? Im at a total loss in arrays...

Comment: give it a shot on your own using what you read in the link then update your post with what you have.  this is not a tutoring site

Comment: I've updated the code with one of the array types i tried it with.

Comment: Just as MSDN's example uses `Debug.WriteLine(numbers(index))` you should use  `Debug.WriteLine(array(index))`

Comment: I did that, but nothing points towards the Label

Comment: [it works for me](https://dotnetfiddle.net/O5PBw0)  Baby steps grasshopper, baby steps.  The first step and core question was how to iterate an array.  Step 1: iterate array to get values step 2 calc average step 3: display

Comment: Okay, so it writes it in the console. But then i need that info, to then make an average number. How do i do that?

Comment: Step 1(a) get the values from the array...I have no idea what the values look like: are they integers? do they have decimals?  Create a variable of the correct type to accumulate the values and add it to the loop

Comment: The values are simple integers - 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. Ill try making a variable

Comment: `Create a` integer `variable to accumulate the values and add it to the loop` - in the loop convert the Lines(n) contents to integer (your textbox.Lines array contains text, not numbers), add the resulting value to the variable you created to accumulate.  Tip: you might want to print out the conversion result to the console to make sure that is correct.  Integer.Parse or Integer.TryParse will work to convert

Comment: Okay, thanks a bunch! Ill try that tomorrow. Thank you for your help and your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly I guess you should have something following this lines:

```
Dim dMods1 = "\\DirectPathToSpecificFolder"


Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If Not dMods1 Is Nothing Then
        For Each FilePath As String In Directory.GetFiles(dMods1, "*.txt")
            TextBox2.Text &= System.IO.File.ReadAllText(FilePath) & vbNewLine
        Next

        Dim arrayVariable As String = TextBox2.Text
        Dim sum As Integer = 0
        Dim count As Integer = 0
        For Each number In arrayVariable.Split(" ")
            Try
                sum += Convert.ToInt32(number)
                count += 1
            Catch 
            End Try
        Next

        Dim average As Double = sum / count
        Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(average)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Made it work with your code. THANKS!! But the `For Each number In arrayVariable.Split(" ")` had to be changed to `For Each number In arrayVariable.Split(vbNewLine)`, because it splits with a `vbNewLine`. But thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome, I'm glad you understood the code and made the necessary changes to it, so it will fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The lesson(s) here ought to have been:

- Programming is not something you just "pick up"
- Most tasks are comprised of several smaller tasks (iterate array, get total, do arithmetic)
- Learning something new often involves several *hours* of research (arrays, iteration, data types, indicies, debugging...) in order to write 10 lines of code
- MSDN has oodles of remdial tutorials, VS even has videos!

### Calculate an average from a string array:

I am assuming the textbox is MultiLine from the code, so each item would be obn its own line.

```
' stand in for textbox lines
Dim Lines As String() = {"1", "3", "5", "2", "8"}
' the accumulator
Dim total As Int32
Dim tmp As Int32

For n As Int32 = 0 To Lines.Count - 1
    ' not all text cant be converted to numbers
    If Integer.TryParse(Lines(n), tmp) Then
        ' Lines(n) could convert to an integer
        ' accumulate the value
        Console.WriteLine("Value at {0} is {1}", n, tmp)
        total += tmp
    Else
        ' bad news!  Lines(n) cant convert!
    End If
Next

' whew! 
' Now the avg:
Dim intAvg = total \ Lines.Count - 1
Console.WriteLine("Integer average is {0}", intAvg)
' float/real version:
Dim fAvg = total / Lines.Count - 1
Console.WriteLine("Fractional average is {0}", fAvg)
```

Comment: It properly works. But i need the result in the `label1`. And before you start saying "This isnt a tutoring site" again, ill try on my own ;) Thanks

Comment: `Label1.Text = fAvg.ToString()`

Comment: Thank you, this works aswell :) Thanks to you, now i've got a better understanding in arrays

Comment: Remember that the first element in an array is at 0, so when you iterate, loop thru one less (`Lines.Count - 1`) and most every programming operation is really a set of several smaller steps